# While loop uses extra variables - can this be cleaned up?

Tags: c#

A piece of my program allows the looping and incrementing of a targeted entity to be used in a while loop somewhere else. Here is a sample of the while loop:

```
while (state.World.Looping(reqComponents))
{
    TimerComponent timer = state.World.GetComponent(TimerComponent.Type);

    if (timer.IsActive)
    {
        timer.TimeLeft -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (timer.IsFinished)
        {
            timer.IsActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the actual loop function, which increments the current entity (which is grabbed by `state.World.GetComponent()`:

```
public bool Looping(ComponentType reqComponents)
{
    if (!isLooping)
    {
        isLooping = true;
        CurrentEntity = 0;
    }
    else if (stopLooping)
    {
        isLooping = false;
        stopLooping = false;

        return false;
    }
    else if (++CurrentEntity == EntityCount - 1)
    {
        stopLooping = true;
    }

    if (!HasComponents(reqComponents))
    {
        return Looping(reqComponents);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The very top part of the `Looping()` feels really ugly to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this code controls everything except the body of the loop: initialization, increment, and destruction. This suggests that the actual `while` should be inside `State.World.Looping`, and it should take another parameter, an `Action` or equivalent delegate, which the caller should pass in. For instance, the call would be rewritten:

```
state.World.Looping(reqComponents, () =>
{
    TimerComponent timer = state.World.GetComponent(TimerComponent.Type);

    if (timer.IsActive)
    {
        timer.TimeLeft -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (timer.IsFinished)
        {
            timer.IsActive = false;
        }
    }
});
```

and `Looping` itself could be modified to:

```
public void Looping(ComponentType reqComponents, Action loopBody)
{
    if (!HasComponents(reqComponents))
    {
       return;
    }
    CurrentEntity = 0;

    do
    {
       loopBody();
    } while (++CurrentEntity != EntityCount - 1);
}
```

I think I got the number of iterations right but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: I really like this approach. I'm trying to think of a way for `Looping()` to not stop if it doesn't have the component. The original code increments the current entity if it doesn't have a component before returning.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to iterate though a sequence of items (in your case, components). So do that: create a method that returns a sequence of components (`IEnumerable<Component>`; `yield return` might be useful for that) that can be iterated using `foreach`, not some weird version of a `while` loop.